# VBA formula to look into different tab based on current tab name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file which contains sheets named V1, V2, V3, ..., V15.
The amount of sheets can vary based on whether or not they exist.

I also have a 'master' sheet which contains the multiplier values in.

What I have done is duplicate each sheet to give V1 (2), V2 (2), ..., V* (2)

The next step is (all contained in range D2:P30):
- in V1 (2), times each value in V1 by the equiv value in multiplier
- in V2 (2), times each value in V2 by the equiv value in multiplier 
- in V* (2), times each value in V* by the equiv value in multiplier

bearing in mind there could be 2 or up to 15 V sheets

Comment: Do you have any sample code? How far have you gotten by yourself? StackOverflow is designed to help people who are stuck, not so much give them free code.

Answer (score 0):

At first:

Tabs are called sheets in vba,

You can select or set them active:

Sheets("sheetname").Select
or Sheets("Sheetname").Activate

can you specify your question?

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to all this stuff!

Comment: Basically I have one 'master' sheet which contains some values. In sheet V1 I have an equivalent set of numbers. I've created a copy of V1 which gives a duplicate sheet called 'V1 (2)'. In 'V1 (2)', I want to multiply these values ='Master'!D2*'V1'!D2. I also have sheet V2 which gives a duplicate sheet called 'V2 (2)'. In 'V2 (2)', I want to multiply these values ='Master'!D2*'V2'!D2, and so on

Comment: @GPol This is possible... do you want to keep the new sheets named V1 (2), V2 (2), etc? Do you want to delete the old V1, V2, etc, sheets? This can be done with a  for loop. Do you want this done in a loop or a macro that's run for each sheet. It might be helpful if you update your question.

Comment: I need the original (v1, v2) sheets but the new sheets can take any name. I have no preference as to how it can be done! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this macro, but run it only once or each time the number of sheets will go up.

```
Sub CopySheetAndSetFormula()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim oldSheet As Worksheet, newSheet As Worksheet, refSheet As Worksheet
    Set refSheet = Worksheets("master")
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If Not sh Is refSheet And Not sh.Name Like "*(*)" Then ' we do not copy the ref sheet, nor the ones with (*) inside
            sh.Copy After:=sh  ' the new sheet become the actve one
            ActiveSheet.Range("D2:P30").Formula = "='" & sh.Name & "'!D2 * 'master'!D2"
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```